# using gdb debug ath5k driver over serial cable

Tags: remote-debugging, kernel-module

I set up following this guide: http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/03/kgdb-with-virtualbox-debug-live-kernel/

but instead of using the virtual machine, I use 2 real machine:
- one is debugger
- second one is target (with equipped wireless card running ath5k driver)

On the debugger machine, I successfully come into

```
$gdb
(gdb)target remote /dev/ttyS0
```

step. Then I use command `(gdb)add-symbol-file` but there is no */lib/modules/3.9.0/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath5k/ath5k.ko*

Are there any wrong in this methodology?

I want to debug the ath5k module so do I need to `#gdb vmlinux` in the fist place?